# conda environment variables not loading in Windows

Tags: python, environment-variables, anaconda, conda

Python 3.6.6 using miniconda.

I followed [the instructions](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables) from the conda docs. I created the `activate.d/env_vars.bat` file and added my variables in there:

`set OAUTH_TOKEN='my-token-here'`

When I activate the variable, the command prompt lists the environments I saved but Python doesn't recognize them:

`NameError: name 'OAUTH_TOKEN' is not defined`

Am I missing a step?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to get the variable from *Python*?

Comment: Nothing. I assumed the variable would just be loaded into the Python environment upon activation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Python*, one way to handle env vars is via [[Python 3]: os.**environ**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ). This is how you would do it for *%OAUTH_TOKEN%*:

```py
os.environ["OAUTH_TOKEN"]
```

**Notice the quotes** surrounding *OAUTH_TOKEN*, which based on your error, you seem to have forgotten.